# Verilog Counter - 50MHz to 1Hz clock

Tags: verilog

How can I use this verilog code to generate a 1Hz clock signal while maintaining the counting functionality? Maxval enables the counter to count up to a certain value and then go back to 0 by reset and start over again. Or, it'll just reset and count again if it hits the maximum value. The thing is, my FPGA has a 50Mhz clock, but I need to use this counter with a 1Hz and a 2Hz clock. Any tips on adapting this code for that purporse?

```
module clocktime(input clk, freerun, Reset, output, input[7:0] Maxval, output reg[7:0] Count, output reg Carry);
    always @ (posedge clk or posedge Reset) begin
        if ( Reset ) begin
            Count <= 0;
            Carry <= 0;
            end
        else
            if ( freerun )
                if ( Count < Maxval ) begin
                    Count <= Count + 8'd1;
                    Carry <= 0;
                    end
                else begin
                    Count <= 0;
                    Carry <= 1;
                    end
        end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with increasing the width of `Maxval` and `Count` variables. You'll need 26 bits to fit a number of 50 millions there. Right now with 8 bits you can divide the clock by 255 at most.

To get additional outputs (1hz, 2hz) you can do something like this:

```
module top(clk50, reset, out_1hz, out_2hz);
input clk50;
input reset;
output out_1hz;
output out_2hz;

reg[25:0] clk50_divisor = 12500000;
reg [1:0] div2_4;

assign out_1hz = div2_4[1];
assign out_2hz = div2_4[0];

wire tmp_4hz;

clocktime div_clk50(
    .clk(clk50),
    .freerun(1),
    .Reset(reset), 
    .Maxval(clk50_divisor),
    .Carry(tmp_4hz));


always @(posedge tmp_4hz)
    div2_4 <= div2_4 + 1'd1;

/* another option, might be better in your particular case,
   or not different at all

always @(posedge clk50)
if (tmp_4hz)
   div2_4 <= div2_4 + 1'd1;

*/

endmodule

module clocktime(clk, freerun, Reset, Maxval, Count, Carry);

input clk;
input freerun;
input Reset;
input [25:0] Maxval;
output reg[25:0] Count;
output reg Carry;

    always @ (posedge clk or posedge Reset) begin
        if ( Reset ) begin
            Count <= 0;
            Carry <= 0;
            end
        else
            if ( freerun )
                if ( Count < Maxval ) begin
                    Count <= Count + 8'd1;
                    Carry <= 0;
                    end
                else begin
                    Count <= 0;
                    Carry <= 1;
                    end
        end

endmodule
```

Comment: This code will generate short (1 clock period width) impulses on `Carry` output, at a frequency of `clk/Maxval`. If you need both 1Hz and 2Hz outputs, you can divide the clock by 25 millions to get 2Hz on `Carry`, and use that output to flip additional register to get a meander at 1Hz.

Comment: So you need specific duty cycle? If meander is ok for you, then set Maxval to 12.5 millions, and feed that Carry into clock of another 2-bit counter (monotonically counting up) to get it divided further by 2 and 4.

Comment: Simulate your code and have a look in the waveform display at how the MSB of `Count` is behaving.